# Is there a light novel for the second season of Sword Art Online anime?

Tags: sword-art-online

I really like Sword Art Online anime and I'm currently watching the second season. I would like to know if there is a light novel for the second season. I already know there is one for the first season, but is there any for the second season?

Comment: you mean GGO arc? all SAO anime series already in light novel right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the second season of Sword Art Online is based on the novel volume 5-6. If they make it 25 episodes like the first season, then it is possible that the anime will cover volume 7 & 8 as well, just like the first season is based on volume 1-4.

While the story is about Gun Gale Online (GGO) and no longer Sword Art Online itself, the novel is still titled Sword Art Online. Currently it is about to be published in western world as Baka-Tsuki has already removed it from their website.

Comment: `about to be published in western world` I doubt it would be any time soon. Probably will be in late 2015, if they keep up the current pace of release.

Comment: Only Gun Gale Online? There 15 light novels and gun gale online is just 5-6th novels. There is alicization arc which occupies 9-15 light novels too.

Comment: With Yen Press's current schedule of 3 volumes a year, Volume 6 should be out in December next year.